# Как вернуть значения функции после нажатия на кнопку в AlertController swift

Tags: swift

возникла трудность с возращением значения в функции. Надо вернуть значения в функцию в зависимости от выбранной кнопки в AlertController.

```
func alertMessange() -> Bool{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Messange", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default){ (alert) -> Void in
//            return true
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel){ (alert) -> Void in
//            return false
        })
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае нужно не возвращать значение, а использовать [closures (замыкания)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html):

```
func alertMessage(after completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    ...
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default){ (alert) -> Void in
        completion(true)
    })
    ...
}
```

И используете где нужно:

```
alertMessage(after: { result in 
    print(result)
})
```